# select parent element class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html code is as follows:

```
<div id="cart-list">
        <div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
            <span class="product-grid-id"   style="display: none;">3</span>
            <div class="product-info col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 product-metadata">
                        <div class="name">Name</div>
                        <div class="price">Price</div>  
                <div class="col-xs-6" id="delete">
                    <button type="submit" name="delete-btn" id="delete-btn">Delete</button>
                </div>

                    </div>
            </div>


    </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
...
</div>
    </div>
```

JQuery is :

```
$(".product-grid-item").on('click','#delete-btn',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).find(".product-grid-id").text();
                deleteFromCart(id);
                return false;
});
```

I want on delete button click, it should select the span element with class name **product-grid-id** and get the text in there, which is 3, in this case and pass it forward..

**NOTE** : There will be many product-grid-item div's in cart-list div. I need to get the id of the div on which the delete button is clicked. this delete button will be in every product-grid-item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `span` element with the `product-grid-id` class is not a child of your current button, and also not a direct parent of it, so what you actually need to do is find a relevant parent and then find the `span.product-grid-id` element inside that parent

To find a parent up the dom-tree you need to use the `parents(SELECTOR)` function, and there you can use the `find(SELECTOR)` function to get the element you are looking for.

This is an example: (note that I commented-out the call to `deleteFromCart` function).

```js
$(".product-grid-item").on('click','#delete-btn',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).parents('.product-grid-item').find(".product-grid-id").text();
  //deleteFromCart(id);
  console.log(id);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart-list">
        <div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
            <span class="product-grid-id"   style="display: none;">3</span>
            <div class="product-info col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 product-metadata">
                        <div class="name">Name</div>
                        <div class="price">Price</div>  
                <div class="col-xs-6" id="delete">
                    <button type="submit" name="delete-btn" id="delete-btn">Delete</button>
                </div>

                    </div>
            </div>


    </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your very quick answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may select the closest:

```
<div class="product-info col-xs-12">
```

and then the previous element `<span class="product-grid-id"   style="display: none;">3</span>`

Th snippet:

```js
$(".product-grid-item").on('click', '#delete-btn', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).closest('div.product-info.col-xs-12').prev('span.product-grid-id').text();
  console.log(id);
  
  // do your stuff
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="cart-list">
    <div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
        <span class="product-grid-id" style="display: none;">3</span>

        <div class="product-info col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-8 product-metadata">
                <div class="name">Name</div>
                <div class="price">Price</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" id="delete">
                    <button type="submit" name="delete-btn" id="delete-btn">Delete</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 product-grid-item">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```